# Elementor Widget Panel Not Loading

Tags: widget, panel, loading, elementor

I have tried like Increased my memory limit to 512M and checked  the PHP version nothing is not working any one could help me about this problem
Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure Elementor is updated.
2. Deactivate all the plugins except Elementor and see if the problem is solved. If yes, trying activating plugins one by one and refreshing the Widget Panel, until you find which plugin is causing the problem.
3. Switch to Wordpress 2022 default Theme and check is this solves the problem. If yes, then there is something wrong with your theme, maybe some modifications you might have made.